# Mysql Update inside loop returns 0 affected rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I have an import from a web service to a MySql database. Web service returns xml format and depending on returned data I have to do INSERT OR UPDATE.

I'm using php mysqli and tested with prepared statements and old style query.

The problem is that updates return 0 affected rows. I knew the WHERE clause was right, so I went to mysql Workbench, write :

```
UPDATE sgji_discounts SET 
                      min_discount = 0,
                      max_discount = 6
        WHERE id = 77
```

And check. The result was 1 affected row. But if I click the bolt button fast, it returns 0 affected rows in the output window.

Do I need to set a sleep between statemets? Is there any special way to execute updates inside a loop?

many thanks

Comment: In fact, it works if I set 1 second sleep but it makes process too long. I could try usleep but I'd like to know if there is another way. Thanks

Comment: can you paste the entire code? the loop. Btw, 0 as affected rows can mean 2 things: 1) 0 rows affected or 2) query hasn't finished yet

Comment: If the data is unchanged, MySQL will report "0 affected rows".  You may also want to consider using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).